# Where clause with conditionals in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following query in my stored procedure (SQL Server):

```
SELECT 
    ea.attendanceid,
    ea.employeeid,

    FROM employee_attendance ea

    WHERE 
    ea.masterentity = @masterentity
    AND ea.employeeid = @employeeid

    -- here I need to know what value @type is and then create my conditionals
    AND (ISNULL(@type,'') = '' OR 
        .......
```

My parameter @type has diferent string values:

- IL = Internal Lunch
- EL = External Lunch
- L = All Lunch
- N = Only Normal
- R = Especial

And depending on the value is the column that I have to filter:

```
If `@type='IL'` then I have to filter: `AND ea.lunchtype = 'C'`
If `@type='EL'` then I have to filter: `AND ea.lunchtype = 'CI'`
If `@type='L'` then I have to filter: `AND ea.islunch = 1`
If `@type='N'` then I have to filter: `AND ea.islunch = 0`
If `@type='R'` then I have to filter: `AND (ea.ismanual = 1 AND ea.lunchtype = 'K')`
```

Any clue on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate into SQL in the similar way

```
AND ( 
ISNULL(@type, ' ') = ' '
OR ( @type='IL' AND ea.lunchtype = 'C' )
OR ( @type='EL' AND ea.lunchtype = 'CI' )
OR (@type='L' AND ea.islunch = 1   )
OR (@type='N' AND ea.islunch = 0    )
OR (@type='R'  AND (ea.ismanual = 1 AND ea.lunchtype = 'K')
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE statement.

CASE can be used in any **statement** or **clause** that allows a valid expression. For example, you can use CASE in statements such as SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and SET, and in clauses such as select_list, IN, **WHERE**, ORDER BY, and HAVING.

[MSDN CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms181765.aspx)

Refer to the examples on this page on howto.